# Magento 1.7.0.2 Forgot password Fatal error

Tags: magento, passwords, fatal-error

When I enter **email address** to retrieve forgotten password it gives the following error after submit. Please help.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1536

Comment: have you modify core magento files?

Comment: No it occurred when I upgrade from 1.5 to 1.7.0.2